# Is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ such that $z^2-x^2-y^2-1 = 0$ open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

As the title says, is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ such that $z^2-x^2-y^2-1 = 0$ open or closed? Moreover, how can I prove it?

I understand the definition of open and closed sets, but I don't get this exercise yet. I've been trying this for days.

Thanks for all help you can give me.

Regards!

Comment: In general the question "open *or* closed?" is not well posed; there are sets that are both. This is addressed in the given answer though.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y,z)=z^2-x^2-y^2-1$. Obviously, $f$ is continuous. Your set is $f^{-1}(\{0\})$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed, your set is closed. Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is connected, your set can't be open, since it is obviously not empty nor the entire $\mathbb{R}^3$.